# Definition of compactly supported functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, compactness

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $f \in C(X)$. Define the support of $f$.
$$\operatorname{supp}(f) := \overline{\{x \in X: f(x) \neq 0\}}$$

I want to show that $$A:=\{f \in C(X)\mid \exists K \subseteq X \mathrm{\ compact \ }: \forall x \notin K: f(x) = 0\}$$

and $$B:=\{f \in C(X): \operatorname{supp}(f) \mathrm{\ is \ compact}\}$$

coincide. The inclusion $B \subseteq A$ is trivial.

**Attempt**: I managed to show that $A \subseteq B$ if $X$ is Hausdorff:

If $f \in A$, determine a compact set $K$ with $f(x) = 0$ for $x \notin K$. Then
$$\{x \in X: f(x) \neq 0\} \subseteq K$$
and taking closures $$\operatorname{supp}(f) \subseteq \overline{K}$$
Since $X$ is Hausdorff, $K$ is closed so we get $$\operatorname{supp}(f) \subseteq K$$

Then $\operatorname{supp}(f)$ is a closed subset of a compact set and we can conclude.

**Question**: Does the inclusion remain valid without the Hausdorff assumption?

Comment: This is a very good question in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. You can take as an example a modification of [the line with two zeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_origin_topology#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20more%20specifically%20general,%E2%88%90%20denotes%20the%20disjoint%20union.) - in particular, let $C$ be an infinite set and let
$$X=C\cup(0,1].$$
Define $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb R$ by
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if }x\in C\\x & \text{if }x\in (0,1].\end{cases}$$
Define a topology on $X$ by saying that a set $U\subseteq X$ is open if and only if $f(U)$ is open. This really does define a topology, though you should carefully check what happens with intersections of open sets.

Clearly, $f$ is continuous. Moreover, if $c\in C$, then $\{c\}\cup (0,1]$ is homeomorphic by $f$ to $[0,1]$ - meaning that $f\in A$ since this is a compact set containing all non-zero values of $f$. However, the support of $f$ is all of $X$, which is not compact because the cover $\{\{c\} \cup (0,1] : c\in C\}$ has no non-trivial subcovers (and hence no finite subcovers). Thus $f\not\in B$.